# Formula with Proportion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to come up with a formula to calculate something.

I have two data that are inversely proportional to one another - width and quantity.

The more quantity the less width.

I know that with $200$ of quantity I can have $3$ of width. So it follows that with $100$ of quantity I can have $6$ of width.

Now, I want to come up with a formula that given a quantity, calculates me the corrispondet width. Taking into account the numbers I wrote on top.

Thanks a lot

Comment: $\text{width}=600/\text{quantity}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

width * quantity $=600$

widths $ = (6,3,2,1.5,1.2,1.0) $ for quantities $=(100,200,300,400,500,600).$